# How to make chrome extension work inside iframe and outside iframe?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Requirement is to find elements via chrome extension.
I have a chrome extension created to highlight web elements on dom.

Below is my **manifest.json**

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "run_at" : "document_idle",
    "all_frames": true,
    "matches":[ 
    "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "js":["jquery-3.1.1.min.js","content.js"]
  }
],
```

**content.js:**

```
document.querySelector('#id'); //Works. Here element is inside iframe.

document.querySelector('.class'); //Fails. Here element is outside iframe.
```

When run, elements are highlighted only in iframes but not which are outside of iframe.
My sample dom structure is like below.

```
<html>
   <head>
      </head>
        <body>
        <div>
        ...
       //elements here not highlighted
        ...
           <iframe>
           ....
               //elements here highlighted
           ....
           </iframe>
        </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

How to make this chrome extension work for both i.e., inside iframe and outside iframe?

Comment: The iframe runs a separate instance of your content script so you should check `window === top` to see if you're in the main page or not. Also iframes without src need `"match_about_blank": true` too.

Comment: Thanks. How do I add window === top check in manifest.json?

Comment: It's JavaScript code in your content script, not json.